# How to detect whether file is XLS or XLSX

Tags: linux, excel, unix

I have an Excel file, but without extension (or the extension cannot be trusted) and I want to detect whether the file is in XLS or XLSX format. How could one do that in Linux?

Comment: This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XLSX is actually a zip archive, which means doing a

```
file excel-file
```

would return for XLSX something like

```
Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

and for XLS something like

```
Composite Document File V2 Document, No summary info
```

Of course in Windows one could simply open the XLSX file with an unarchiver.